# Convert photo (jpg or any format) to .rda

Tags: r

Hi: Is there any way i can convert any photo (preferably jpg format) to .rda file so that I can do PCA analysis? My objective is to convert photo to rda. Take first few components of from pca do the similar operation to another photo file so that i can compare them..

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? Tool requests are considered off topic here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `.rda`? You can import it into an R object, e.g. a `matrix` and run a PCA on that.

```
library(jpeg)

download.file("http://art.ngfiles.com/images/71000/71640_rozas_biolove.jpg", destfile = "biolove.jpg")
xy <- t(readJPEG("biolove.jpg")) # needs more rows than columns, so t() is used here

xyp <- princomp(xy)

summary(xyp)
```

## edit

This example will be more permanent. Converting back to original image has been discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57467/how-to-reconstruct-original-data-using-a-small-number-of-principal-components) (follow question comments as well).

```
xy <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
image(xy[,, 1])
pca <- princomp(t(xy[,, 1]))

fig <- (pca$scores %*% t(pca$loadings))
image(fig)

pca2 <- prcomp(t(xy[,, 1]), center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
image(pca2$x %*% t(pca2$rotation))
```

Comment: @XXavier open a new question. Make sure you give a reproducible example (you can just copy/paste my code and add what you've tried).